# I want to show Native_Ads_view In XML file in Android Studio but it give me error

Tags: android

Basically my problem is that when I add native_ads_view in XML file it give me error ("Required XML_attribute "adSize" was missing").

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#72B2D1"
    tools:context=".SplashScreen">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:adSize="BANNER"
        app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView
        android:id="@+id/sndNativeAds"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2247696110"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="300x200"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_move"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/adView">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_move"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:text="Move To Next"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Error

```
Required XML_attribute "adSize" was missing
```

Comment: Try setting ad size in java side.

Comment: how can i do that please can you send me a piece of code for an example.

Comment: I know it's weird solution but can you try to invalidate cache and restart in android studio ?

Comment: or to set it in java you can do this final AdView adView = new AdView(getActivity());
adView.setAdUnitId("YourId");
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);

Comment: (When posting questions here, please keep your posts clear and succinct. Greetings, how stuck you are, how much you have searched, that you are waiting for an answer, etc are all irrelevant, and are best not added. They only clutter up your post and make it less readable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution, it will work if you use it like this:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView
 android:id="@+id/adView"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 ads:adSize="FULL_WIDTHx80"
 ads:adUnitId="@string/native_ad_unit"/>
```

Or  It has been solved when I added the `NativeExpressAdView` programmatically and removed it from `XML` as follows.

```
nativeAd = new NativeExpressAdView(this);
int widthInDP = context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenWidthDp;
    widthInDP -= context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.activity_horizontal_margin);
nativeAd.setAdSize(new AdSize(widthInDP, 250)); 
nativeAd.setAdUnitId("myAdUnitId");

// Create an ad request.
AdRequest.Builder adRequestBuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();

// Optionally populate the ad request builder.
adRequestBuilder.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR);

// Add the NativeExpressAdView to the view hierarchy.
layout.addView(nativeAd);

// Start loading the ad.
nativeAd.loadAd(adRequestBuilder.build());
```

Or it may resolve by invalidating cache and restart your android studio or **Try changing the size to** `ads:adSize="300x250"` will work damn sure.

Comment: did u face same error on applying my suggestion @shanimalik

Comment: thank you sir now it's working fine...i use this step invalidating cache and restart android and error is solved